# What can change in the rods?

Tags: magikarp-jump

Every time I go to fish a Magikarp, I get the choice between 3 rods... that are seemingly all the same.

What is that choice? What is the variance between the 3 rods?

Comment: Does this help? https://pokemongohub.net/magikarp-jump/patterns/

Comment: I have no data to back this up, but it seems to me that it's just done this way for comedic effect. Your "choice" isn't really a choice. Even if our choice does have some effect, there doesn't appear to be any way of knowing.

Comment: @ZAD-Man I don't think it's comedic; I think it's because people like to get superstitious about influencing random events, and this makes them feel like they have some control. I bet almost everyone has a favorite rod or some ritual to choose a rod.

Comment: @Kat Yeah, very well could be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as we know at this point, all three rods are identical from the user's point of view.  The game may roll three different Magikarp, or it may simply roll one; given you know nothing to differentiate between the three those would be identical from a probabilistic point of view.

I've done a little research, but not statistics-level yet, to see if the choice seems to have any correlation to the type of bonus you get; in my research it doesn't seem to.  I believe the three rods are a meaningless choice.

Answer (score 1):

The rods are only **possibly** related to the magikarp you will catch. This can be proven because you can manipulate the game to give you different magkiarp after the rod has been chosen.

When you are standing on the dock fishing you will see a dialog box that has beads of sweat in it. It will flash on screen 1 to 3 times. This indicates the rarity of the magikarp you will catch. If, for example, you only get 1 dialog box pop up (which would indicate a tier 1 magikarp), you could immediately close the game and reopen it. The game will prompt you to pick a rod (you can pick the same rod you did last time) and you will go back to the dock. Once at the dock you can now receive a different rarity of magikarp.

Somewhere, either at the point when you pick your rod or when you are standing on the dock, the game determines what tier of magikarp you will catch. It is unknown if whether the rod has influence on this or if it is purely influenced by the scene at the dock.

One might speculate that the rods are linked to a tier and that when you reload the game it causes them to reroll their tiers. Another option is that the rods are an empty choice and that only the scene determines the magikarp.

So to answer the question, there is a possibility that the rod will determine the rarity of the magikarp you catch.

Answer (score -3):

No, not all the rods are the same. The different rods will help you catch [different styles of Magikarps](https://mic.com/articles/178189/magikarp-jump-patterns-these-lovely-fish-come-in-all-sizes-and-colors#.heUabuFQN).

While you may start the game with 3 of the same rod (which I suspect is why they appear the same to you right now), as you progress through the story more rods will be unlocked. These will then allow you to catch new types of Magikarp ([source](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/210334-pokemon-magikarp-jump/75391946)).

So far, the current Magikarp you can catch are:

**Old Rod**

- Standard
- Skelly
- Calico
- Gold

**So-so Old Rod**

- Orange Two-tone
- Orange Orca
- Orange Dapples

**Good Old Rod (available after Fast League)**

- Pink Two-tone
- Pink Orca
- Pink Dapples

**Great Old Rod (available after Fast League)**

- Gray Bubbles
- Gray Diamonds
- Gray Patches
- Purple Bubbles
- Purple Diamonds
- Purple Patches

Pictures of all these different patterns of Magikarps can be seen [here](https://pokemongohub.net/magikarp-jump/patterns/).

Comment: I don't think this answers the question - Q asks whats the difference between the three rods you get to pick from

Comment: @KevinL Well, the answer is that they allow you to catch different Magikarps. If you don't think this is clear in my answer feel free to suggest an edit, but I think given the information in the question the content of my answer properly answers the question

Comment: @KevinL am I completely misunderstanding the question?

Comment: I believe so. The question asks "What is the difference between the 3 rods you get to pick from (left, middle, right)". You answer the question "What is the difference between the different types (old, so-so, good, great) rods"

Comment: @KevinL Maybe I can edit it to be clearer - functionally, as far as I can tell, the only differences are in the types of Magikarps that can be caught. Maybe I could identify which rod is which?

Comment: From the Q: " I get the choice between 3 rods... that are seemingly all the same." -> If all three rods are the same type of rod, does picking a rod do anything?

Comment: @KevinL updated, hopefully this is better. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @B.S.Morganstein But you never have the choice of multiple rods, do you?  I always only have 3 identical rods, and I'm rank 30...

Comment: Also, Good Old Rod is available _during_ the Fast League, so it would be available after the Great League.

Comment: @B.S.Morganstein The edit appears to have reinforced the misunderstanding.

Whenever you fish up a new Magikarp, you are given a "choice" between three rods of the exact same type. It doesn't matter that there are other types of rods because you can only ever choose one rod type.

When you unlock a new rod, you lose the option to select any of the previous ones, so it appears that you aren't really making a choice at all.